# how to show all item with a checkbox in form yii2

Tags: forms, list, checkbox, yii2

Im trying to make an assistance.

I have 2 tables(Asistencia and Mecanico) In the Asistencia form I need to list all Mecanico so user check more than one mecanico.

So far i have this

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'mecanico_id')
    ->dropDownList(
    ArrayHelper::map(Mecanico::find()->all(), 'id_mecanico', 'nombre'),['prompt'=>'Choose one Mecanico'])
?>
 <?php $model->asiste = "asiste"; ?>
<?= $form->field($model, "asiste")->checkbox([true => 'si', false => 'no']); ?>
```

[image: my form]

That get all mecanico but i can only choose one and check if he came or not but doing that for every single person is not worth it, so i want to list them all, and next to them a check box so it would be easier to pass assistance

[image: form that i want to have]

Comment: I am a bit lost in the explanation pls can you improve it a bit. May be screen captures o more code will help

Comment: tell me what you didnt undersant and i will try to explain more

Comment: either you need `multi-select` by reading the description, or you need multiple checkboxes by looking at the image of the form you want?

Comment: Or you need an extra checkbox to do all at ones?

Comment: i dont need multi select, multi checkboxes would work but idk how to implement

Answer (score 0):

I have the feeling you may need to use a checkboxList.

Then you can send your data to it as an array.

```
<?php 
   $list = [0 => 'Morning', 1 => 'Noon', 2 => 'Evening'];
   echo $form->field($model, 'name[]')->checkboxList($list);
?>
```

You may add later an extra checkbox manually to be able to select them all at ones, and help users.

Some more about it here: https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-widgets-activefield#checkboxList()-detail

Hope this helps.